# Can I add elements to global array from parallel executed functions in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

I have NodeJS script, which run functions in parallel (using async-each). 
I need to store results of all functions in one array. Can I use global array for that or it  will cause access conflict (like with threads in Java) ?

If it will cause conflict, how can I store(accumulate) results from parallel functions in one variable/array?

UPDATED. For example, code snippet

```
var each = require('async-each');
var resultsArr = [];
var rawData = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,65,3,33,44,55];
each(rawData, (element, callback) => {
   console.log('element:' + element);
   var calculateResult = (element * 2)/ 3 + 10; 
   resultsArr.push(calculateResult); 
   callback(null);
}, (err, rawDataModified) => {
    console.log(resultsArr);
```

});

I test this example snippet on my local machine and all works fine (no freezing of script as in my work version - it very big to post it here). It mean parallel functions(iterators) of async-each can access global array without problems/access conflicts?

Comment: Please share a bit of your code so that we can understand more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: node.js is single threaded so they don't run at the same time but they, depending on how they are coded, can cause problems in the event loop, you can always use callbacks that use nextTick() to ensure that the two operations don't run in parallel, but without knowing what your code looks like, we have no idea what the problem is. Using a global array pollutes the global namespace and is not necessary.

Comment: It means iterator functions in the snippet above don't run at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js (or any javascript engine) will only ever execute function at a time. In a single node.js program, there's never 2 threads of javascript running. So this is not something you have to worry about.

Comment: But can be in Node.js 2 or more parallel operations? Iterator functions in example above runs in parallel?

Comment: No, node.js does *not* execute code in parallel. The only thing that can happen in parallel is IO operations, such as disk access and network access.